# Append text at the cursor position in Summernote JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flutter, webview

I'm developing a flutter app in which I'm using summernote editor which is made using JQuery.

```
ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);

String txtIsi = data.text
  .replaceAll("'", '\\"')
  .replaceAll('"', '\\"')
  .replaceAll("[", "\\[")
  .replaceAll("]", "\\]")
  .replaceAll("\n", "<br/>")
  .replaceAll("\n\n", "<br/>")
  .replaceAll("\r", " ")
  .replaceAll('\r\n', " ");

String txt = "\$('.note-editable').append( '" + txtIsi + "');";

_controller.evaluateJavascript(txt);
```

Basically what this function does is take data from Android Clipboard and append that data to the end to what I am writing in the Summernote editor. Is there a way I can add text at the cursor position rather than the end?

Answer (score 0):

To insert the text at the current cursor position:

```
_controller.evaluateJavascript("\$('#summernote').summernote('focus');").then((value) {
      print('focus == = $value');
    });

_controller.evaluateJavascript("\$('#summernote').summernote('insertText', 'YOUR TEXT');").then((value){
      print('insertText == = $value');
    });
```